# Unable to load spaCy model in Google colab

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

So, I'm running this in my Google Colab notebook:

```py
import spacy
!python -m spacy download fr_core_news_lg
```

But what I'm getting it that:

```
✘ No compatible model found for 'fr_core_news_lg' (spaCy v2.2.4).
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colab is serving spacy 2.2.4, but the model you'd like to download is not yet available in that version. Update spacy to the newest version first:

```
!pip install --upgrade spacy
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think models would be version-dependent!